# Segmentation fault while using sprintf() in do while / for loops

Tags: c, printf

I'm using sprintf - sscanf combination to rounding floating decimals and did it this way

```
float rounding(float number)
{
    char* rounded_number;
    float rounded;
    sprintf(rounded_number, "%.2e", rounded_number);
    sscanf(rounded_number, "%e", &rounded);
    return rounded;
}
```

And I called it once outside a loop and once in a loop. Trying outside any loop gives expected results, but calling

```
for (int j = 1; j < 101; j++)
    printf("%f", rounding( 1.0 / ((float) j)));
```

gives a segmentation fault.

Can someone explain?
Thanks.

Comment: You have to allocate some memory for `rounded_number`. As an uninitialised pointer, this is *undefined behaviour*. Note that you are also dividing by 0.

Comment: `char* rounded_number;` -> `char rounded_number[32] = {0};`

Comment: @WeatherVane I tried `char *rounded_number = malloc(sizeof(float));` It doesn't work either.

Comment: @SreenadhaSaranga your array-of-chars has to be large enough to hold all of the generated characters, plus a NUL terminator byte.  `sizeof(float)` is 4, which is probably not large enough.

Comment: If `sizeof float` is `4` how will that buffer hold say `123.456789`? Don't use such tiny buffers: it's not your wallet.

Comment: With j = 0 you try divide 1.0 by zero.

Comment: @Elec1 I ran from j = 1 in my code. Typed a mistake here.

Comment: And why did you post a programme which runs from j = 0?

Answer (score 0):

Your `sprintf` call has undefined behavior because the destination pointer is uninitialized, to `sprintf` tries to write to some random location in memory, most likely causing a segmentation fault.

Furthermore, you pass `rounded_number` instead of `number` as the argument for `%.2e` which is another case undefined behavior.

You should use `snprintf` and pass a local array:

```
float rounding(float number) {
    char buf[32];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.2e", number);
    sscanf(buf, "%e", &number);
    return number;
}
```

Note however that the *rounded* number will not represent the exact values with 2 decimals in many cases. Floating point types use a binary encoding that cannot accurately represent most decimal fractions: only whole multiples of `1`, `0.5` and `0.25` are accurately represented.